# How to pass tableView label to name variable in another viewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm creating an app for a school project, and I have a tableView with a label inside which contains the name of the cell, and I am trying to pass the name of the label to the navTitle variable on my second viewController. I have tried multiple ways of achieving this but have had no luck.

I have tried printing the passed title but it prints the output 'nil'

**Home view**

```
var names = ["Accomodation", "Facilities", "Things To Do", "About"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
    }
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "homeCell", for: indexPath) as? homeTableViewCell
     
        cell?.label.text = names[indexPath.row]

        return cell!
    }
    
    //Passing data
    var nameChosen : String?
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        nameChosen = names[indexPath.row]
        
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "accomodationSegue", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as? accomodationViewController
        destinationVC?.navTitle = nameChosen
    }
```

**Accomodation view**

```
var navTitle: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      
        print(navTitle)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

Comment: Is `prepareForSegue` called at all?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to pass the name as `sender` parameter, the property `nameChosen` is not needed.

And it's good practice to check the identifier of the segue in `prepare(for segue`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    let name = names[indexPath.row]
    
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "accomodationSegue", sender: name)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard segue.identifier == "accomodationSegue" else { return }
    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! accomodationViewController
    destinationVC.navTitle = sender as! String
}
```

If the code crashes you made a design mistake.

And please name classes always with starting uppercase letter (`AccomodationViewController`).

Comment: I have tried this answer but I'm still getting the output of 'nil' when going to the next viewController. could this be as the navTitle is being set as 'sender' instead of 'name'?

Comment: The code must work if everything is hooked up correctly in Interface Builder.

Comment: Everything is hooked up correctly but is still outputting nil. I am not sure why, I have rewritten the code, copy and pasted and edited it slightly but none of it works.

Comment: Did you check what Sweeper already asked: *Is `prepareForSegue` called at all*?